# Universal Analytics cross domain tracking a subdomain on external damain

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

I'm about to implement Universal analytics cross domain tracking on two separate domains.
domain 1: example.com
domain 2: sub.example2.com

To domain 1 i'm adding:

> ga('require', 'linker');
>
> ga('linker:autoLink', ['*.sub.example2.com']);

To domain 2 i'm adding:

> ga('create', 'UA-domain 2', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
>
> ga('require', 'linker');
>
> ga('linker:autoLink', ['example.com'] );

The main area im unclear on is if this part is correct

> ['*.sub.example2.com']

Or can I just use

> ['sub.example2.com']

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a substring comparison not a REGEX. So the right answer should be:

```
['sub.example2.com']
```